# How to debounce and throttle API calls in a TypeScript-React application?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a TypeScript-React application that needs to make API calls based on user input.
To not overload the server i would like to minimize the amount of calls to the API.

To achieve this, I'd like to implement both debounce and throttle techniques. Debounce will prevent multiple API calls when the user is typing, and throttle will limit the number of API calls made within a specific time frame.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface Props {
  onSearch: (query: string) => void;
}

const SearchInput: React.FC<Props> = ({ onSearch }) => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Call the API when `searchText` changes.
    onSearch(searchText);
  }, [searchText]);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      value={searchText}
      onChange={(event) => setSearchText(event.target.value)}
    />
  );
};
```

I have seen examples of debounce and throttle implemented separately, but I would like to combine both in my React application. Can anyone provide an example or suggest a clean and efficient approach to achieve this?

Comment: Debounce and throttle should be composable; the output of the debounce should be the input to the throttle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I got you right, what you're looking for is called "leading-edge debounce with trailing-edge throttle"

Not to reinvent the wheel, I would suggest taking a look on https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce
which provides with `useDebounce` hook, that has `leading` and `maxWait` setting out of the box, so will allow you to configure leading debounce (from example()

```
const [text, setText] = useState('Hello');
const [value] = useDebounce(text, 1000, { leading: true, maxWait: 2000 });
```

In this way, when you call `setText` the first time - it will update the `value` immediately. If you'll call `setText` more times within the delay time defined in the second argument (1000 milliseconds in our example) - they will be commonly denounced, so the last one will be applied in 1 sec after the last input. But `maxWait` makes some additional magic, preventing long user inputs without updates. So, using `maxWait`, when you continue to call `setText` for a while - it will update the value once per `maxWait` value (2 sec in our example).